# Error-free conversion of OTF fonts to WOFF format

Tags: fonts, woff

I need to convert some OTF fonts to WOFF format for web use, but I'd like to avoid display errors for the converted fonts.

Is there a process to ensure my resulted WOFFs are OK? Are web converters like cloudconvert or convertio reliable in producing error-free conversions?

Answer (score 0):

Most reputable foundries provide fonts in a variety of formats, including WOFF fonts for web use (assuming the licence covers that usage). So you might not need to do the conversion yourself.

I'd suggest that 'desktop software' is more reliable than web converters -- and of course I have my suspicions about what happens to these font files once you've uploaded them to a third-party.

I'm unaware of what 'display errors' might be possible within the WOFF format. A quick google doesn't bring up much -- this page being the top hit!